# lightbox2 doesn't open image in lightbox

Tags: lightbox, lightbox2

I try to integrate Lightbox2 in an existing website.

Head Code:

```
<head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" type="text/css" href="/css/style.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/lightbox.css">

 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/lightbox.js">
</head>
```

Image Code:

```
<div class="image-wrapper">     
 <a href="/img/projects/folder/image_big.jpg" data-lightbox="lightboxImage">
  <img src="/img/projects/folder/image_thumbnail.jpg" alt=" " class="project-image">
 </a>
</div>
```

My problem is when I click the thumbnail it only opens the big image in a blank browser window instead of opening it in a lightbox.

I already checked the paths. And the browser console shows no errors.

I think I just missed something. But I don't know what it could be.

Would appreciate some help. Thank you!

Comment: Are you sure that href="/img/projects/folder/image_big.jpg" is correct? This is why is opening a new window. Shouldn't be href="#" or something?

Comment: At the lightbox2 website it says:

<a href="images/image-1.jpg" data-lightbox="image-1" data-title="My caption">Image #1</a>

So I think it's correct.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to instruction from the [Lightbox2 Homepage](http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/#getting-started) you have to put the script tag refering to `/js/lightbox.js` file at the bottom of the `</body>` tag.

> Include the Javascript at the bottom of your page before the closing `<body>` section:
>
> ```
> <script src="path/to/lightbox.js"></script>
> ```

Comment: It works!
Like i said. I missed something or rather mixed something up!
Big Thanks! :)